# Unusual evaluation of $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume the formula $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+u)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi u)^2},$$ where $u\notin\Bbb Z$. I have been trying to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$Setting $u=1/2$, I was able to derive $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8},$$but I haven't made any progress toward proving the value of $\zeta(2)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: In sum of squares, divide it into sum of even terms and sum of odd terms. Then take the 1/4 out from the sum of even terms.

Comment: the assumption formula seems interesting ... however I can't find it on google? can you give me links? (+1)

Comment: @experimentX: It comes from Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis textbook. I was able to prove the formula by integrating $$f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(u+z)^2}$$ over the contour made up of a circle of radius $N+1/2$ with $N\geq|u|$. With the correct bounds, you can show the integral goes to $0$, then use the residue formula. The summation question came as additional exercise from my professor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Splitting the sum into odd and even parts:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{(2n+1)^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{(2n+1)^2}$$

$$\frac 34 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{(2n+1)^2}$$

and it's trivial from there.

Answer (score 6):

A more direct way of seeing this is to do the following. Break up the sum as
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{1}{(n+u)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+u)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi u)}-\frac{1}{u^2}$$
and take $u\to 0$. This is easiest to do by Taylor expanding
$$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi u)}=\frac{1}{u^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{3}+\frac{\pi^4 u^2}{15}+\cdots$$
so we see that the singularity cancels exactly and we have
$$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$

Comment: This is a good technique as well. Thank you for the insight.